# How do you prioritize requests on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

For my website it's hard to think of a global Minimum Pending Latency. My website would be much more efficient if I could specific which requests should be prioritised. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do it; you might want to star [this](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5775) specific feature request.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I was really looking for was Deferring Tasks. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push.html#Deferred_Tasks.